# uninitialized values with valgrind - pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, valgrind

I'm currently using valgrind to check my program, and a small test program gave me errors that I cannot understand:

```
int size=10;
int i;

float * v1;
v1=new float[size];

float v2[size];

for (i=0;i<size;i++) v1[i]=0;
for (i=0;i<size;i++) v2[i]=0;

v1[0]=1;
v2[0]=1;
```

v2 works fine, but v1 gives a Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value error on valgrind.

Why does this happen? Also, is it best practice to use arrays as in the v2 above, or is it the same?

thanks in advance.

edited: added the rest of the code - errors appear on

```
v1=new float[size];
for (i=0;i<size;i++) v1[i]=0;
v1[0]=1;
```

Comment: valgrind doesn't track stack allocated memory in all cases. Chances are you have the same error in v2, but valgrind won't be able to report it. Also, show the valgrind output, and the lines of code that valgrind complains about - valgrind shouldn't complain about the few lines of code here, so you have more code somewhere.

Comment: Why would uninitialised variables be giving _error_?

Comment: A *member* of `v1[]` (and possibly `v2[]` as well as nos says) is not initialized. Use `v1 = new float[size] = {0.0};` or similar. You really should show anything in `//do stuff` that reads `v1[]`, since it's likely that Valgrind is right about your logic and that you do have a deeper bug hidden there.

Comment: It shouldn't be an error... unless `//do stuff` reads from the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Probably because you read the memory before you initialize it.

EDIT: according to the code that you've added, you don't read the memory before initialization. It seems that valgrind is just paranoid and the error is a false positive. If you intend to set all elements to the same value, it would be simpler to use value initialization though.

> Also, is it best practice to use arrays as in the v2 above

Yes, but not because there is no error. Reading uninitialized stack memory is just as wrong as reading uninitialized dynamic memory.

In general, variables with automatic storage duration are preferred to variables with dynamic storage duration. Unless the array is huge, in which case you don't want to use up valuable stack space. Or if `size` is not compile time constant in which case you can't allocate it on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You have dynamically allocated memory for v1 but did not initialized it. It could contain anything at this point.